# How are these arrows supposed to be interpreted?

Tags: notation

I was reading a computer security paper recently and they gave the following definition of a hyperproperty defined over 4 program traces called "TPOD":

---

Let the four traces be $\pi_1$, $\pi_2$, $\pi_3$, $\pi_4$, and the trace property $T$. Suppose the following assumptions hold:

1. traces $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ satisfy the trace property $T$,
2. traces $\pi_3$ and $\pi_4$ do not satisfy the trace property $T$,
3. all four traces execute the same low operations,
4. traces $\pi_3$ and $\pi_4$ execute execute the same high operations
   as $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ respectively,
5. traces $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are low-equivalent and the initial states
   of $\pi_3$ and $\pi_4$ are low-equivalent.

Then, TPOD is satisfied if $\pi_3$ and $\pi_4$ are low-equivalent.

---

They then display the equation in the paper using notation:

[image]

For reference, $\pi_1\approx_\mathcal{L}\pi_2$ indicates the traces $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are low equivalent, and $op_\mathcal{L}(\pi)$ and $op_\mathcal{H}(\pi)$ are the low and high operations, respectively, of a trace $\pi$.

What I'm confused about is the fact that they used multiple arrows. It makes it seem like condition 1 implies condition 2 and so on, which is not what the text implied. I'm assuming that all 4 statements are supposed to be a "bundle" that together imply that last statement? Or am I incorrectly interpreting the statements? Is this notation common in papers?

Comment: Correct: 1st line implies 2nd line that implies 3rd ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little confusing, but it appears that $A \to B \to C$ is not a sequence of implications here; i.e., it is not saying $A \to B$ and $B \to C$. It is the single logical statement $A \to B \to C$. By convention, the arrow associates to the right, i.e. $A \to B \to C$ means $A \to (B \to C)$, which is equivalent to $(A \wedge B) \to C$. So your interpretation is correct; the statement is (equivalent to) saying that the first 4 statements imply the last.

Although the notation in the paper is logically correct, it is potentially confusing and for that reason, I wouldn't write it that way without a very good reason.